# Python: Validation problem for specific ints

Tags: python, validation, integer

I have a list,  list = ["Dog", "Cat"]
and printed out an enumerated list, e.g.
0 Dog
1 Cat

I want the get the user to choose one (using an input command)
Then I want to validate the input to make sure it's 0,1 (with future versions going from 0 to 20 for other animals too).
My attempt at validation uses some help I recently received (tq) to make sure the input was an int. I've added a further check, to make sure that the int was one of the acceptable numbers, by previously dumping the animal lists index (when printing the enumerated animal list), into a new list [0,1] called "list_with_valid_numbers_to_choose_from". I want to print out the users number input at the end. It all works perfectly, EXCEPT when I input a zero, then I get "True" as the result and not what I want, which is 0. I've tried a few ways to force an actual 0 number to be returned but have run out of ideas.

```
def get_number(no_elements, list_with_valid_numbers_to_choose_from):
        while True:
            print(f"no_elements= {no_elements}") # I don't actually use no_elements in this function.
            value = input("Enter the number of the animal you want to choose: ")
            try:
                if value := int(value) or value == "0":   # Conversion to an int was fine
                    # now check to see if the int is a valid option
                    for element in list_with_valid_numbers_to_choose_from:      # e.g. [0,1] from ["Dog", "Cat"]
                        if element == value:
                            print(f"value= {value}")
                            if value == 0:
                                del(value)
                                value=0
                                return 0
                            return value
                raise ValueError("There are no animals (check to see if you created one earlier), OR, you didn't enter a valid number according to the choices given")
            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)
```

If say the returned 'True', is because the condition of the while True statement was met, then how on earth to escape this and actually return a variables value?

Comment: *if value := int(value) or value == "0":* makes no sense. If the call to int() causes a ValueError then the second part of the condition will not be evaluated. If it does not fail then it can't possibly by "0" because it will be an int. Are you just trying to validate an index into some list?

Comment: If I remove the tagged on  `or value == "0"`   part, then the code never accepts 0 as a valid input and asks me to re-enter a number, so it makes sense in being able to avoid the error when 0 is infact a valid input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a briefer way to do this, using builtin methods.

```
def get_number(valid_numbers):
    while True:
        input_value = input("Enter the number of the animal you want to choose")
        if not input_value.isnumeric():
            print('Non-integer value entered')
        else:
            number = int(input_value)
            if number in valid_numbers:
                return number
            print('Animal not found')
```

Comment: Thanks :)
Always nice to see (better)variations by more seasoned coders.. I like the way your method avoids what feels like the 'hanging' for loop in my variation.

Comment: In general, you don't need to be worried about breaking out of for loops before they end - indeed, it's good practice to break them before they end if you find a result, because that typically makes code more efficient. There aren't any side effects to worry about

Comment: Wow. This title appeared on my YouTube video shorts list....
"Python Devs Always FORGET That THIS Exists" by  "Indently" (YouTube - see the shorts section) and it gives a nice efficient way if checking if a variable/value appears in a list. V. relevant to what I'm doing. (AI scanning my cookies???)

Comment: Indently is a great informative channel - his videos on `itertools` and string methods are good references, on par with the documentation. I would however warn that he mixes his terminology up on occasion, such as "list comprehension" vs "generator expression" in that particular video

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with this and it works perfectly, chiefly from the help already received on stackoverflow - much appreciated! Although I wonder will breaking out of an uncompleted for loop cause any issues???

```
def get_number(list_with_valid_numbers_to_choose_from):
    while True:
        value = input("Enter the number of the animal you want to choose: ")
        try:
            x = int(value)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Enter a number shown on the list")
            continue  # OK. value is an int....
        
        value = int(value) # converting input string into an int
        
        for element in list_with_valid_numbers_to_choose_from:   # e.g. [0,1] from ["Dog", "Cat"]
            if value == int(element):
                print(f"No. is valid,  Number was: {value}")
                return value
        print("There are no animals (check to see if you created one earlier), OR, you didn't enter a valid number according to the choices given")
```